# How to animate an element sliding out of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have an element positioned at the bottom of the page, and I want to animate it sliding out of view.

In my implementation, the element is not actually vanishing, but rather just sliding down, such that if you scroll down, you will still be able to see it.

How can I implement this animation such that the element actually disappears and does not affect page size while sliding down?

```js
visible = false;

const container = document.querySelector('.cta-container')

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  visible = !visible

  if (visible) {
    container.classList.remove('hidden')
    container.classList.add('visible')
  } else {
    container.classList.remove('visible')
    container.classList.add('hidden')
  }
})
```

```css
.cta-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 24px;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-right: 64px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.header {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.content {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.mat-elevation-z5 {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)
}

.hidden {
  transform: translateY(190px);
}

.visible {
  transform: translateY(-16px);
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle visibility</button>

<div class="cta-container mat-elevation-z5 hidden">
  <h1 class="header">Do something</h1>

  <p class="content">Yada yada</p>

  <button>Ok</button> <button>No</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you considered `position: fixed` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position: fixed...
But I also do some code simplifications...

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.cta-container')

document.querySelector('button').onclick =_=> 
  {
  container.classList.toggle('noShow')
  }
```

```css
.cta-container {
  position         : fixed;
  bottom           : 16px;
  left             : 24px;
  padding          : 16px;
  padding-right    : 64px;
  background-color : white;
  transition       : all 0.2s;
  }
.cta-container.noShow {
  transform  : translateY(190px);
  }
.cta-container:not(.noShow) {
  transform  : translateY(-16px);
  }
.mat-elevation-z5 {
  box-shadow : 0px 3px  5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2 )
             , 0px 5px  8px  0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14)
             , 0px 1px 14px  0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  }
.header {
  font-size     : 20px;
  margin-bottom : 8px;
  }
.content {
  font-size : 16px;
  }
```

```html
<button>Toggle visibility</button>

<div class="cta-container mat-elevation-z5 noShow">
  <h1 class="header">Do something</h1>

  <p class="content">Yada yada</p>

  <button>Ok</button> <button>No</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply changing to `position: fixed` will make this work as you want.  I've added a bunch of paragraphs of text to make the page scroll so you can see how this works on different sizes of pages, and that the dialog box will stay in that fixed position on the screen regardless of page size or scroll position.

```js
visible = false;

const container = document.querySelector('.cta-container')

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  visible = !visible

  if (visible) {
    container.classList.remove('hidden')
    container.classList.add('visible')
  } else {
    container.classList.remove('visible')
    container.classList.add('hidden')
  }
})
```

```css
.cta-container {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 24px;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-right: 64px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.header {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.content {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.mat-elevation-z5 {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)
}

.hidden {
  transform: translateY(190px);
}

.visible {
  transform: translateY(-16px);
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Toggle visibility</button>

<div class="cta-container mat-elevation-z5 hidden">
  <h1 class="header">Do something</h1>

  <p class="content">Yada yada</p>

  <button type="button">Ok</button> <button type="button">No</button>
</div>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>


<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
```